# browser won't open in gmail api

Tags: java, browser, gmail-api

When I run my application for the first time without the StoredCredential file saved, the program fails to open the browser. Then, when I manually open the browser, go to the printed link, and hit okay to allow access to my account, the program doesn't continue running. Every time I run the program, it does this actually.

The program prints out something like this each time (only link changes):

```
2016-08-31 22:15:53.250:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2016-08-31 22:15:53.250:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2016-08-31 22:15:53.258:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:35268
Please open the following address in your browser:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=723296789344-l7b6jp5ffkmeteokur8qmi5fd8rkont5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:35268/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...
```

As i said, the given link doesn't open automatically and when I do it manually and accept access to my account, the program doesn't continue running. Any ideas what might be going on? Also, if it's helpful, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with the default browser set correctly.

Also, does anyone have any idea where to start on implementing account authentication in the OAuth framework?

Answer (score 3):

***Reason:***

This problem occurs because of the  **google api**  **AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.class** class.

The class is used to check 
**Desktop.isDesktopSupported()**. It always returns false , so the code throws an exception,because it does not work on all OS platforms.

***Solution:***

Create your own custom **class** just like **AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.class**.

Keep all codes the same, just add this  **else** part

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {

}
else {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
}
```

Now, to get the credential,  use

```
Credential credential= new YourClassName(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Instead of:

```
Credential credential= new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is handled by Class *GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow* and *Credential* objects. In the [Java Quickstart for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java), you can see how this is implemented:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
    GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
    GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
    .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
    .setAccessType("offline")
    .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
    flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
    "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
    }
```

Here's some note about [How authorization works](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) in Gmail:

At a high level, all apps follow the same basic authorization pattern:

1.During development, register the application in the Google API Console.

2.When the app launches, request that the user grant access to data in their Google account.

3.If the user consents, your application requests and receives credentials to access the Gmail API.

4.Refresh the credentials (if necessary).